# datagridview row data overlapped with old datasource row data while changing datasource

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I am changing datasource which is a list with radiobutton change , but the data of row from old datasource is getting overlapped in the first selected row of the datagridview. it gets clear when new row is selected.
I have set selection back colour of row and header to transparent.

[image]
datagridview row is overlapped here with old datasource data.

```
private void rb_allmat_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rb_allmat.Checked) // radiobutton checked.
        {
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource =  
CommonClass.ListofthresholdIndication; // this is a list that is to be displayed.
dataGridView1.Update();
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            colorchange();
            changecolorofheader(); 
        }
```

Comment: Please share the code in the question itself instead of image of the code.

Comment: you need to share the code in the question. Not in comment...

Comment: pardon. I am new here. i have shared my code.

Answer (score 0):

use `datagridview1.Rows.Clear()`